# fixed button on a page view controller swift

Tags: swift, button, uipageviewcontroller

Is there any way to add a fixed button to a page view controller?[image]

In the above picture i would like to have the `Close` button fixed i.e. do not move away when different view is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Embed in a NavigationController or add a navigationBar and put a BarButtonItem in it.

Comment: but i dont want a NavigationController.

Comment: Just curious... What are the reasons against embedding in a NavigationController?

Comment: Because i am displaying this current view as modal since it is a page view controller.